# Javascript accesing file

Tags: javascript, file

I need a function made using pure JS for accessing specific line of text file. I was looking for same questions and answers similar to this one but I couldn't find anything that matches my problem perfectly. I'm a beginner dev so I can't modify even the most similar programs (for example some which are returning whole file) so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

use this code example if you know how to modify it (scroll down if not):

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");

fileInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);

  reader.onload = () => {
    const lines = reader.result.split("\n");
    const thirdLine = lines[2];
    console.log(thirdLine);
  };
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
```

---

### How to Use?

use a demo file like this `demo.txt`:

```
my line example 0
my line example 1
my line example 2
my line example 3
my line example 4
```

and `[2]` should output the third line with "my line example 2"

[image]

---

### Documentation:

| concept | link |
| --- | --- |
| <input> file | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file |
| new FileReader() | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader |
| .readAsText() | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText |
| .split() | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split |
| array | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array |
| eventListeners | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener |

---

## if you don't know coding at all

## here a copy-paste code

you just have to change the number in the variable `NUMBER_OF_THE_LINE`...

 or call the function with `.then()` for complex scenarios

1. copy
2. paste in notepad or vscode
3. save and call this file `demo.html`
4. open in your browser
5. ...

> also I tried to put a lot of comments so you can understand since you said: "I'm a beginner dev so I can't modify even the most similar programs so that's why I am asking".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- HTML file input element -->
  <input type="file" />

  <script>
    const NUMBER_OF_THE_LINE = 2; // change this to the line number you want to read

    readLineNumber(NUMBER_OF_THE_LINE).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      // your code (change here the code using the "res" variable)
    });

    // don't change the code below... it's just a helper function

    async function readLineNumber(n) {
      // Select the file input element (select the first one if there are multiple)
      // you can use id="" or class="" to select the element if you want, but this is the easiest if there isn't any other input element
      const fileInput = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Set up an event listener that will be triggered when the file input value changes (i.e. when a file is selected)
        fileInput.addEventListener(
          "change",
          () => {
            // Get the selected file
            const file = fileInput.files[0];

            // Create a new FileReader object
            const reader = new FileReader();

            // Read the file as text
            reader.readAsText(file);

            // When the file is read, do something with it
            reader.onload = () => {
              // Split the file into an array of lines
              const lines = reader.result.split("\n");

              resolve(lines[n]);
            };
          }, {
            once: true, // Remove the event listener after it's triggered
          },
        );
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```